# Kafka Console consumer with kerberos authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, apache-kafka, kerberos

How to consume published messages from the kafka (version 0.10) server which was kerberos  authorized, for the authentication keytab file is being used.

I tried with the below command but no outputs were shown.

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server :9092 --topic  --from-beginning

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Kerberos-enabled clusters can pose some tricky challenges at times. I've had to deal with some of these myself.

If the Kafka Cluster is Kerberos-enabled then you'll need to supply a *jaas.conf* file with the Kerberos details. Try following these steps(they worked for me):

1. Create a *jaas.conf* file with the following contents:

> ```
> KafkaClient {
> com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
> useKeyTab=true
> keyTab="<path-to-the-keytab-file>"
> principal="<kafka-principal>";
> };
> ```

Note: I've assumed that the Kafka principal and the associated keytab is already created. If not, you'll need to create these first.

2. Create a properties file (say "consumer.properties") with the following contents:

> ```
> security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
> sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
> ```

3. Then at the terminal run the following command:

> ```
> $export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path-to-jaas.conf>"
> ```

4. Execute the Kafka-console-consumer script:

> ```
> $ kafka-console-consumer --topic <topic-name> --from-beginning 
> --bootstrap-server <anybroker>:9092 --consumer.config <consumer.properties>
> ```

EDIT - Steps 3 and 4 could be combined just in case there is a preference to keep these as one command in the command history.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i find it helpful to combine steps 3 and 4 e.g.

`$ KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path-to-jaas.conf>" kafka-console-consumer --topic <topic-name> --from-beginning 
--bootstrap-server <anybroker>:9092 --consumer.config <consumer.properties>`

Therefore the entire command is in your terminal history (assuming you use that).

Comment: @jambox - Thanks a lot for your suggestion. :) I've also used it for the same reason but for this answer I thought of keeping these 2 separate to explain the commands/steps better. But I'm adding this as an edit anyway just so people reading this are aware of it as well.